# tbb::parallel_reduce on std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, tbb

The below is a simple parallel program to calculate the sum of elements in a standard vector using tbb.
Can someone please help me understand why it is outputing a wrong result?

```
#include  <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

#include <tbb/tbb.h>

struct Sum {
    int value;

    Sum() : value(0) {}
    Sum(Sum&s, tbb::split) : value(0) {}

    void operator()(const tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<int>::iterator>& r) {

        value = std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), 0);
    }

    void join(Sum& rhs) { value += rhs.value; }
};


int main()
{   
    std::vector<int> a(100);
    std::fill(a.begin(), a.end(), 1);

    Sum sum;
    tbb::parallel_reduce(tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<int>::iterator>(a.begin(), a.end()), sum);

    std::cout << sum.value << std::endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you use `accumulate` wrong. It should be

```
value = std::accumulate(r.begin(), r.end(), value);
```

Comment: usually, it is `value += `.. it's just `std::accumulate()` which provides another way to write `value = sum + value`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the functional form of `tbb_parallel_reduce`? It avoids the need for your `struct Sum` and looks more intuitive, for example (not tested)

```
typedef tbb::blocked_range<std::vector<int>::iterator> range_type;
auto sum=tbb_parallel_reduce(range_type(a.begin(),a.end()), 0,
                             [](range_type const&r, int init)
                             { return std::accumulate(r.begin(),r.end(),init); },
                             std::plus<int>());
```